Help with getting a manual for these sets please
Hi I have lost the boxes and manuals to these sets. But the bags are intact.
Says 721S3 on the bags.
When I scan the QR code it says 6172090. I looked on the LEGO website. It brings up multiple items. The 721S3 number brings up nothing.
The other bags, scanning the QR code brings up 6172062. But again doesn't provide anything on the website.


Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

This question is similar to: How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi Jim and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take a look at the linked duplicate question and the answer posted there - if you have any problems following those steps, let us know and we'll update the process. Have fun and play well!

That's set 31137 because of lavender 3x3 round corner brick, and set 31126 because of 8x8 black radar dish.

Thanks so much
